# Starting linear scale from 1 instead of 0 (D3.js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I'm trying to create a line graph with D3.js and I want my X axis to start from 1 instead of 0.
The code looks as follows:

```
    var temp = [36.5, 37.2, 37.8, 38.2, 36.8, 36.5, 37.3, 38.2, 38.3, 37];

    var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,temp.length]).range([0, w]);
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).tickSize(-h).tickSubdivide(false);

        graph.append("svg:g")
              .attr("class", "x axis")
              .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
              .call(xAxis);
```

When I change this to:

```
    var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([1,temp.length]).range([0, w]);
```

the scale get's edited but the graph starts outside of the graph itself.
I tried to use tickvalues but I can't get this to work.

How can I let my scale start from 1?

Comment: What do you mean by "the graph starts outside of the graph itself"?  How are you setting the x-positions of your data points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you are labeling your axis by using the index of the data.

When you set your domain starting at 1, you're actually just telling your chart to make the left-most part of your graph be the x-coordinate of the *second* datum (index 1).

When you actually create the chart, there is a datum (index 0, value 36.5) that is outside of your defined domain, and d3 uses linear extrapolation to determine where it should be placed, making it end up to the left of the start of your chart.

What you really want to do is start your domain at 0, so that the first datum is in your domain, but to reformat your tick labels so that they show the index incremented by 1.

You can use `axis.tickFormat()` to do this.

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .tickSize(-h)
  .tickFormat(function(d) { return d + 1; })
```

---

Side note: you shouldn't specify `.tickSubdivide(false)`, since:

1. That function expects a number, not a boolean, and `false` will be coerced to `0`.
2. The default value is `0` anyways.
3. `axis.tickSubdivide` is deprecated and does nothing as of version 3.3.0